# How to tell IdentityServer 4 middleware not to authenticate if earlier middleware has already done so?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-middleware

My ASP.NET Core REST API uses 2 authentication middleware - JWT to authenticate users (tokens issued by ADFS), and IdentityServer to authenticate calls from other services.  The configuration for those middleware looks like this:

**JWT**

```
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new X509SecurityKey(federationMetadata.GetSigningCertificate()),
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuer = federationMetadata.GetIssuerUri().AbsoluteUri,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidAudience = validAudience,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
};

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
});
```

**Identity Server 4 (IDS)**

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = dbConfig.IdentityServer.AbsoluteUri,
    ScopeName = Configuration.ServiceName,
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false
}
```

I am having problems with this setup:

When a user passes a token from ADFS, the JWT middleware successfully validates the token.  The IDS middleware then cannot validate the token and throws an error:

```
IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey , KeyId: <MyRsaKey>
```

This is expected.  How can I tell the IDS middleware not to authenticate if an earlier middleware has successfully authenticated the request?

I've tried a couple of things.  It seems to me that the ideal would be to work out on the IDS `OnMessageReceived` event that the user has been authenticated, and tell the IDS middleware to do no further checking:

```
JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents()
{
    OnMessageReceived = async (context) =>
    {
        if(UserIsAlreadyAuthenticated)
            DoNothingMore();
    }
}
```

- How could I test if the user is authenticated?
- How do I tell the middleware to accept the authentication and do no more processing?

I have tried trapping the IDS `OnAuthenticationFailed` event and skipping the middleware:

```
OnAuthenticationFailed = async (context) =>
{
    if (context.Exception is IdentityServerNotAvailableException)
    {
        context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
    }
}
```

but I then get a scope validation failure:

```
Scope validation failed. Return 403.
```

Where is the scope validation happening?  Because it seems that any error in the IDS middleware results in a scope validation error, whether I `SkipToNextMiddleware` or not.

If I remove the IDS middleware, everything works.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:** I have solved the scope validation issue for now.  I tried setting the `ValidateScope = false` option on the IDS middleware, but this causes a *null reference exception* inside the middleware; but I've found that if I comment out the `ScopeName = Configuration.ServiceName` option, the scope validation issue is solved (I handle it in a custom handler - not ideal).

**Still need to know:** Either how to tell the IdentityServer middleware to skip if the token has been authenticated successfully, or to identify successful previous authentication in the `OnMessageReceived` event so I can call `SkipToNextMiddleware()` there myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get IdentityServerNotAvailableException?

Comment: No.  I am running my implementation of IdentityServer4.  If I shut it down then I get a different error when the IdentityServer middleware is invoked (after the JWT middleware has validated the token): `System.IO.IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://localhost:5555/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A connection with the server could not be established`

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Core or OWIN? UseJwtBearerAuthentication should've been obsolete starting from version 1